# Is there a way to build an interactive node graph in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, graph, vis.js, vis.js-network

I'm looking to build an interactive node graph on a webpage where you can add nodes with various inputs and outputs and connect them together.

This is an example of what I'm looking to do:

[image]

I started to play around with [vis.js](http://visjs.org/) but I'm not sure it will be able to do the above.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Have a look at [d3.js](https://d3js.org/) as an alternative - refer to the 'Examples' link as well as [here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock) for examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, such broad questions in form of "is it possible to ...?" are frowned upon at StackOverflow, but the direct answer would be "yes, it is possible" and moreover, vis.js has an [example](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/examples/network/other/manipulation.html) of a manipulatable graph so I recommend you to read [the manupulation methods docs](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/#methodManipulation) and [the manipulation module docs](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/manipulation.html) which describe methods like `addNode`, `editNode`, `deleteNode` etc.

However, you should note that all the interfaces are usually implemented outside the graph-containing canvas, in html (+js) because it's not trivial to put them inside canvas and, say, show attached to all nodes.

Answer (score 8):

For those who (like me) trying to find js libraries for creating interactive graphs here is the list:

*Click on images for better quality.*

[react-flow](https://reactflow.dev/) | [demo](https://reactflow.dev/docs/examples/overview/)

[image: react-flow preview]

[vis-network](https://github.com/visjs/vis-network) | [demo](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/examples/network/basic_usage/peer.html)

[image: vis-network preview]

[DAG-ToDo](https://github.com/ishowta/DAG-ToDo) | [demo](https://todo.iwata.love/)

[image: DAG-ToDo preview]

[flowy](https://github.com/alyssaxuu/flowy) | [demo](https://alyssax.com/x/flowy/)

[image: flowy preview]

[jsplumb](https://github.com/jsplumb/jsplumb) | [demo](https://demo.jsplumbtoolkit.com/community/flowchart/)

[image: jsplumb preview]

[react-diagrams](https://github.com/projectstorm/react-diagrams) | [demo](http://projectstorm.cloud/react-diagrams/?path=/story/simple-usage--canvas-drag)

[image: react-diagrams preview]

[butterfly](https://butterfly-dag.gitee.io/butterfly-dag/home) | [demo](https://butterfly-dag.gitee.io/butterfly-dag/demo/dagreLayout)

[image: butterfly preview]

[Drawflow](https://github.com/jerosoler/Drawflow) | [demo](https://jerosoler.github.io/Drawflow/)

[image: Drawflow preview]